# How to get the previous version back after installation

Tags: installation

Help need 2.79 version back. Im not yet familiar with 2.8. I download & installed the new version 2.8. Thinking it will install separately but it overlap the older version. All my settings and addon install disappeared and i have 2.8 version. How can i get back 2.79 version and my settings and addon back.

Comment: It's not looking good for your settings and addons :( https://developer.blender.org/T67965

Comment: You can download 2.79 versions from here https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/
Best use the archive version for your platform (.zip, tar.bz2, tar.gz) because you can simply extract them and use without installing. So that won't cause any conflicts. You'll need to download and install your add-ons again.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is download the blender 2.79 zip (portable) file. Unzip the file into your program files folder (if you are on windows). Then run the blender.exe that is in that folder.

https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/

[image]